# Krpano viewer with map Leaflet OSM

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, openstreetmap, mapping

i'm new in krpano
I'm looking for adding a map (OpenStreetMap) in the Virtual tour of krpano, OpenLayers or Leaflet, that should be interactive with panoramic viewer, so every panoramic image has representative point in the map, every changing in viewer 360 change in the map, and every changing in the map change the viewer. a good example of my specifications is : http://rabat.carte.ma/view/rabat.php i have a code to start with (if you want) that have only the radar.

i found a plugin that swhows Leaflet Map (OSM)

but the map is not interactive, and spots in the map added manually

[plugin Leaflet](https://github.com/adodo1/krpano/blob/master/plugins/leafletmaps.js)

tour.xml

```
<krpano version="1.20.9" title="SONACOS">
<include url="arrows.xml" />

<include url="skin/vtourskin.xml" />

<!-- customize skin settings: maps, gyro, webvr, thumbnails, tooltips, layout, design, ... -->
<skin_settings maps="false" maps_type="satellite" maps_bing_api_key="" maps_google_api_key="" maps_zoombuttons="false" maps_loadonfirstuse="true" gyro="true" gyro_keeplookingdirection="false" webvr="true" webvr_keeplookingdirection="true" webvr_prev_next_hotspots="true" autotour="false" littleplanetintro="false" followmousecontrol="false" title="true" thumbs="true" thumbs_width="120" thumbs_height="80" thumbs_padding="10" thumbs_crop="0|40|240|160" thumbs_opened="true" thumbs_text="false" thumbs_dragging="true" thumbs_onhoverscrolling="false" thumbs_scrollbuttons="false" thumbs_scrollindicator="false" thumbs_loop="false" tooltips_buttons="false" tooltips_thumbs="false" tooltips_hotspots="false" tooltips_mapspots="false" deeplinking="false" loadscene_flags="MERGE" loadscene_blend="OPENBLEND(0.5, 0.0, 0.75, 0.05, linear)" loadscene_blend_prev="SLIDEBLEND(0.5, 180, 0.75, linear)" loadscene_blend_next="SLIDEBLEND(0.5,   0, 0.75, linear)" loadingtext="" layout_width="100%" layout_maxwidth="814" controlbar_width="-24" controlbar_height="40" controlbar_offset="20" controlbar_offset_closed="-40" controlbar_overlap.no-fractionalscaling="10" controlbar_overlap.fractionalscaling="0" design_skin_images="vtourskin.png" design_bgcolor="0x2D3E50" design_bgalpha="0.8" design_bgborder="0" design_bgroundedge="1" design_bgshadow="0 4 10 0x000000 0.3" design_thumbborder_bgborder="3 0xFFFFFF 1.0" design_thumbborder_padding="2" design_thumbborder_bgroundedge="0" design_text_css="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial;" design_text_shadow="1" />

<layer name="menu_button" keep="true" url="menu_bottom/menu_button_orange.png" visible="true" crop="0|0|64|64" align="rightbottom" x="10" y="10" scale="0.5" onclick="menu_toggle();">
</layer>

<style name="menu_thumbborder" keep="true" url="menu_bottom/menu_item_border.png" visible="true" enabled="false" align="lefttop" scale="1" ox="0" oy="0" scale9grid="1|1|247|52"/>


<layer name="map" keep="true" alturl="./plugins/leafletmaps.js" align="rightttop" x="0" y="0" width="500px" height="30%" key="AIzaSyD8zAwIBmvpNHY7oKkGD06qIiZ6OssapuM" maptype="satellite" lat="34.928999" lng="-2.315626" zoom="16">
    <spot name="scene_360_5000_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.315802" lat="34.92898" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_5000_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4999_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.315885" lat="34.928974" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4999_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading="" linkedscene="scene_360_4999_Stitch_XHC"/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4998_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.315986" lat="34.928965" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4998_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4997_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.316074" lat="34.928953" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4997_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4996_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.316156" lat="34.928946" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4996_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4995_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.316245" lat="34.928941" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4995_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4994_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.31634" lat="34.928933" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4994_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4993_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.316424" lat="34.928922" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4993_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4992_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.31571" lat="34.928993" heading="270.0" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4992_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" />

    <spot name="scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.315626" lat="34.928999" heading="64.5" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" />

    <spot name="scene_360_4992_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.31571" lat="34.928993" heading="270.0" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4992_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" />

    <spot name="scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC" active="false" lng="-2.315626" lat="34.928999" heading="64.5" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" />

    <spot name="scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC" title="scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC" active="true" lat="34.928999" lng="-2.315626" heading="0" onclick="alert('Helo');loadscene(scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" />

    <radar visible="true" zoomwithmap="true" size="50" />
    <maptypecontrol visible="true" buttonalign="V" />
</layer>
<!-- <layer name="map" keep="true" url="bingmaps.swf" alturl="./plugins/bingmaps.js" align="lefttop" x="0" y="0" width="30%" height="30%" key="AIzaSyD8zAwIBmvpNHY7oKkGD06qIiZ6OssapuM" maptype="normal" lng="-2.31571" lat="34.928993" zoom="15">

    <spot name="scene_360_5000_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.315802" lat="34.92898" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_5000_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>
    <spot name="scene_360_4999_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.315885" lat="34.928974" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4999_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>
    <spot name="scene_360_4998_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.315986" lat="34.928965" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4998_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>
    <spot name="scene_360_4997_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.316074" lat="34.928953" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4997_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>
    <spot name="scene_360_4996_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.316156" lat="34.928946" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4996_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>
    <spot name="scene_360_4995_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.316245" lat="34.928941" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4995_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>
    <spot name="scene_360_4994_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.31634" lat="34.928933" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4994_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>
    <spot name="scene_360_4993_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.316424" lat="34.928922" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4993_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" heading=""/>

    <spot name="scene_360_4992_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.31571" lat="34.928993" heading="270.0" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4992_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" />

    <spot name="scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC" lng="-2.315626" lat="34.928999" heading="64.5" onclick="loadscene(scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC,null,MERGE,BLEND(1));activatespot();" />

    <radar visible="true" zoomwithmap="true" size="20" />

    <maptypecontrol visible="true" buttonalign="V" />
</layer> -->

<!-- <include url="skin/vtourskin_design_flat_light.xml" /> -->
<!-- <include url="skin/vtourskin_design_glass.xml" /> -->
<!-- <include url="skin/vtourskin_design_ultra_light.xml" /> -->
<include url="skin/vtourskin_design_117.xml" />
<!-- <include url="skin/vtourskin_design_117round.xml" /> -->
<!-- <include url="skin/vtourskin_design_black.xml" /> -->

<!-- startup action - load the first scene -->
<action name="startup" autorun="onstart">
    if(startscene === null OR !scene[get(startscene)], copy(startscene,scene[0].name); );
    loadscene(get(startscene), null, MERGE);
    if(startactions !== null, startactions() );
</action>


<scene name="scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC" title="scene_360_4991_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4991_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="-2,315626" lng="34,928999" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4991_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_1_%s.png" />
    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="8.089" atv="32.996" linkedscene="scene_360_4992_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>
<scene name="scene_360_4992_Stitch_XHC" title="scene_360_4992_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4992_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="-2,315626" lng="34,928999" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4992_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />
    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_2_%s.png" />
    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot2" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-175.274" atv="38.373" linkedscene="scene_360_4991_stitch_xhc" />
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-2.961" atv="22.459" linkedscene="scene_360_4993_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>
<scene name="scene_360_4993_Stitch_XHC" title="scene_360_4993_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4993_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="-2,315626" lng="34,928999" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4993_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />
    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_3_%s.png" />
    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot2" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-175.274" atv="38.373" linkedscene="scene_360_4992_stitch_xhc" />
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-6.249" atv="2.804" linkedscene="scene_360_4994_stitch_xhc" />
</scene>




<scene name="scene_360_4994_Stitch_XHC" title="360_4994_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4994_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4994_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_4_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="0.105" atv="9.633" linkedscene="scene_360_4995_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_4995_Stitch_XHC" title="360_4995_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4995_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4995_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_5_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-4.487" atv="3.124" linkedscene="scene_360_4996_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_4996_Stitch_XHC" title="360_4996_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4996_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4996_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_6_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-3.134" atv="11.436" linkedscene="scene_360_4997_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_4997_Stitch_XHC" title="360_4997_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4997_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4997_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_7_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-4.799" atv="13.401" linkedscene="scene_360_4998_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_4998_Stitch_XHC" title="360_4998_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4998_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4998_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_8_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-4.695" atv="12.214" linkedscene="scene_360_4999_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_4999_Stitch_XHC" title="360_4999_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_4999_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_4999_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_9_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-9.837" atv="12.865" linkedscene="scene_360_5000_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_5000_Stitch_XHC" title="360_5000_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_5000_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_5000_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_10_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="14.961" atv="29.519" linkedscene="scene_360_5001_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_5001_Stitch_XHC" title="360_5001_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_5001_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_5001_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_11_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="83.837" atv="19.382" linkedscene="scene_360_5002_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_5002_Stitch_XHC" title="360_5002_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_5002_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_5002_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_12_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="35.225" atv="8.392" linkedscene="scene_360_5003_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_5003_Stitch_XHC" title="360_5003_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_5003_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_5003_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_13_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="-33.667" atv="-0.648" linkedscene="scene_360_5004_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>

<scene name="scene_360_5004_Stitch_XHC" title="360_5004_Stitch_XHC" onstart="" thumburl="panos/360_5004_Stitch_XHC.tiles/thumb.jpg" lat="" lng="" heading="">

    <control bouncinglimits="calc:image.cube ? true : false" />

    <view hlookat="0.0" vlookat="0.0" fovtype="MFOV" fov="120" maxpixelzoom="2.0" fovmin="70" fovmax="140" limitview="auto" />

    <preview url="panos/360_5004_Stitch_XHC.tiles/preview.jpg" />

    <image>
        <cube url="cube_panos/panorama_14_%s.png" />

    </image>
    <hotspot name="spot1" style="skin_hotspotstyle" ath="2.724" atv="-12.133" linkedscene="scene_360_5005_stitch_xhc" />

</scene>
```

[The code-source](https://github.com/adodo1/krpano)

Comment: And what would krpano be?

Comment: panoramic viewer for 360 degrees images